# Submersion or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, education

How can I prove that $$ f : \mathbb R \rightarrow  \mathbb R, f(x) = e^x$$ is a submersion? I know that I must prove that $$f’= e^x$$ is everywhere  surjective. But how can I write it? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following the definition, we have to show that for all $x\in \mathbb R$ the differential:
\begin{equation}
df_x:T_x\mathbb R\rightarrow T_{f(x)}\mathbb R
\end{equation}
Since $T_x\mathbb R = \mathbb R$ we have only have to show that, fixed $x\in \mathbb R$, the linear application 
\begin{equation}
df_x:\mathbb R\longrightarrow \mathbb R, \quad
v\longmapsto df_x(v) = f'(x)\cdot v = e^x\cdot v
\end{equation}

So the only thing you have to check is that for all $x\in \mathbb R$, $df_x$ is not the zero map, and this is true because $e^x>0$. Then $f$ is a submersion.

Comment: Sorry, but I’ve not convinced yet!                    Why $$e^x$$ is not surjective?

Comment: Hi! When you speak about submersion, you don't have to prove that function $e^x$ is surjective; you have to prove that  for all $x$ the linear map $df_x$ that send a vector $v\rightarrow e^x v$ is surjective. So $x$ in this case is fixed. I give you an example: I want to show that $f$ is a submersion at point $x=2$. I have to check that the map $df_2:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $v\mapsto e^2 \cdot v$ is surjective, and this is obvious because a it is just a multiplication by $e^2$ that is a number different from $0$. If I was not clear, ask me again :)

Comment: I also edit the last line of the answer, maybe it was ambiguos.

Comment: I know, but I think I get confused. Why do you write the differential of $$f$$ like it? I say why the differential of $$f$$ is surjective while $df$$ itself is not? Because I consider both of them as $$e^x$$?

Comment: If you have time, come to this room 
https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106181/differentialgeometry